# How do I add a score tracker?

Tags: python, pygame

So I want it to count the score every time the snake eats a candy.

I haven't tried much, but I tried to find existing codes and adding them to mine but that just broke the game. I also tried to make my own score board by watching a tutorial, but I don't know where the code should go like at the beginning or end.

```py
import pygame
import random

score = 0

welcome = ("Welcome to our snake game")

print(welcome)


class cube:
    height = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(movee,start,x=1,y=0,color=(0,0,0)):
        movee.pos = start
        movee.x = 1
        movee.y = 0
        movee.color = color


    def move(movee, x, y):
        movee.x = x
        movee.y = y
        movee.pos = (movee.pos[0] + movee.x, movee.pos[1] + movee.y)

    def draw(movee, surface, eyes=False):
        leng = movee.w // movee.height
        i = movee.pos[0]
        j = movee.pos[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, movee.color, (i*leng+1,j*leng+1, leng-2, leng-2))



class snake:
    body = []
    turns = {}
    def __init__(movee, color, pos):
        movee.color = color
        movee.head = cube(pos)
        movee.body.append(movee.head)

    def move(movee):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    movee.x = -1
                    movee.y = 0
                    movee.turns[movee.head.pos[:]] = [movee.x, movee.y]

                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    movee.x = 1
                    movee.y = 0
                    movee.turns[movee.head.pos[:]] = [movee.x, movee.y]

                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    movee.x = 0
                    movee.y = -1
                    movee.turns[movee.head.pos[:]] = [movee.x, movee.y]

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    movee.x = 0
                    movee.y = 1
                    movee.turns[movee.head.pos[:]] = [movee.x, movee.y]

        for i, c in enumerate(movee.body):
            p = c.pos[:]
            if p in movee.turns:
                turn = movee.turns[p]
                c.move(turn[0],turn[1])
                if i == len(movee.body)-1:
                    movee.turns.pop(p)
            else:
                if c.x == -1 and c.pos[0] <= 0: c.pos = (c.height-1, c.pos[1])
                elif c.x == 1 and c.pos[0] >= c.height-1: c.pos = (0,c.pos[1])
                elif c.y == 1 and c.pos[1] >= c.height-1: c.pos = (c.pos[0], 0)
                elif c.y == -1 and c.pos[1] <= 0: c.pos = (c.pos[0],c.height-1)
                else: c.move(c.x,c.y)




    def add(movee):
        tail = movee.body[-1]
        dx, dy = tail.x, tail.y

        if dx == 1 and dy == 0:
            movee.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]-1,tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx == -1 and dy == 0:
            movee.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0]+1,tail.pos[1])))
        elif dx == 0 and dy == 1:
            movee.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]-1)))
        elif dx == 0 and dy == -1:
            movee.body.append(cube((tail.pos[0],tail.pos[1]+1)))

        movee.body[-1].x = dx
        movee.body[-1].y = dy


    def draw(movee, surface):
        for i, c in enumerate(movee.body):
            if i ==0:
                c.draw(surface, True)
            else:
                c.draw(surface)

def drawingAGrid(w, height, surface):
    sizein = w // height

    x = 0
    y = 0

    for l in range(height):
        x = x + sizein
        y = y + sizein






def redrawGrid(surface):
    global height, width, s, snack
    surface.fill((255,255,255))
    s.draw(surface)
    snack.draw(surface)
    drawingAGrid(width, height, surface)
    pygame.display.update()



def Candy(height, item):

    positions = item.body

    while True:
        x = random.randrange(height)
        y = random.randrange(height)
        if len(list(filter(lambda z:z.pos == (x,y), positions))) > 0:
            continue
        else:
            break

    return (x,y)



def gameloop():
    global width, height, s, snack, x_pos, y_pos, reset
    width = 500
    height = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    s = snake((255, 0, 0), (10, 10))
    snack = cube(Candy(height, s), color=(0, 0, 0))
    flag = True


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    x_pos, y_pos = s.body[0].pos

    while flag:

        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(7)
        s.move()
        x, y = s.body[0].pos

        if not -1 <= x - x_pos <= 1 or not -1 <= y - y_pos <= 1:
            movee.reset((10,10))



        x_pos, y_pos = s.body[0].pos
        if s.body[0].pos == snack.pos:
            s.add()
            snack = cube(Candy(height, s), color=(0, 0, 0))









        redrawGrid(win)




gameloop()
```

I just want like a scoreboard in any of the corners counting the score.

Comment: Can you at least TRY to put it somewhere and see what breaks? Logically, you should be increasing the score everytime you are at the same position as the candy and the scoreboard should be drawn inside the gameloop (since it is constantly updated)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) to render text. e,g, crated a [`pygame.freetype.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.SysFont) object:

```py
import pygame.freetype
```

```
pygame.init()
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
```

The score is the number of body parts. Use [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) to convert a number to a text and [`.render()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452310/how-do-i-add-a-score-tracker) to render a text to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
score = len(s.body)
text_surf, text_rect = font.render(str(score), (255, 0, 0), size=30)
```

Define a margin to the border of the window, calculate the text position (e.g. bottom right) and `.blit` the text to the window surfrace:

```py
margin = 10
text_pos = (width - text_rect.width - margin, width - text_rect.height - margin)
surface.blit(text_surf, text_pos)
```

Function `redrawGrid`:

[image]

```py
def redrawGrid(surface):
    global height, width, s, snack
    surface.fill((255,255,255))
    s.draw(surface)
    snack.draw(surface)
    drawingAGrid(width, height, surface)

    score = len(s.body)
    text_surf, text_rect = font.render(str(score), (255, 0, 0), size=30) 
    margin = 10
    text_pos = (width - text_rect.width - margin, width - text_rect.height - margin)
    surface.blit(text_surf, text_pos)

    pygame.display.update()
```